# Stop at first character match?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I want to fetch a certain html node in a large html text, but something in my regex is bad.

I want to fetch all urls that look like this:

```
<a href="ftp://mysite.com"> some stuff </a>
```

I am trying to do:

```
/<a href="ftp:(.+)">/
```

but sometimes it will work, but sometimes it will grab everything until the next close `>`.

Is there a way to rewrite this regex so it will stop at the first `>`?

Comment: `+` is greedy by narure. You need to make it non-greedy by adding `?` quatifier after `+`. so your regex would be, `<a href="ftp:(.+?)">`

Comment: Just use `[^"]*` if you want it to match everything until the `"`, instead of `.+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is a **greedy** operator meaning it matches as much as it possibly can and still allows the rest of the regex to match. For this, I recommend using a negated class meaning  any character except: `"` "one or more" times.

```
/<a href="ftp:([^"]+)">/
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zY2vU9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Make your regex ungreedy:

```
/<a href="ftp:(.+?)">/
//        here __^
```

or:

```
/<a href="ftp:([^>"]+)">/
```

But it's better to use a parser.

Answer (score 1):

`*`, `+` are greey (matches as much as possible). By appending `?` after them, you can make non-greedy.

```
/<a href="ftp:(.+?)">/
```

or you can specify exclude `"` using negated character classes (`[^...]`):

```
/<a href="ftp:([^"]+)">/
```

[BTW, it's not a good idea to use regular expression to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/2225682)